# Blender not responding when I try to export fbx with baked auto rig pro armature with animations

Tags: animation, export, .fbx, auto-rig-pro

I've been using Auto Rig Pro for rigging, animating and exporting my character(humanoid for Unity), and it worked fine so far. I have made a copy of already existing character(that I previously made and exported actions from) and created multiple actions for it. Now, I can't export any type of fbx with baked animations. Exporting without animations works fine.
I've tried to export ten different iterations of my character, from Blenders 2.8, 2.82 and 2.82a, to no avail.

Update 1:
Even when I tried to append the action to different blender file(the one from witch I've previously exported fbx with animations), it still doesn't work. Same problem, Blender becomes unresponsive. This means that problem is probably within action itself. I just need to find out what it is.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't answer, because you're further along than I am. I can't get to the export stage because I'm still trying to use ARP to finish my animations. One step at a time, right? But I wanted you to know that I've created an Auto Rig Pro chatroom on this site. I'm hoping what few ARP users there are will be able to meet there and support each other. I fear that there may be a minimum reputation score required to join a chatroom, however. If true, that would be a shame. I get the impression that a lot of ARP users are posting here once on that topic alone. They might not be able to join.